# Domino Data Services REST requests keep giving error 404

Tags: rest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I followed the quick setup [here](http://www.browniesblog.com/A55CBC/blog.nsf/dx/09042013111234MBRF6E.htm) to get DDS running.  Pretty sure I did it correctly, but when I attempt a REST GET request against a test application, it just returns a 404 all the time.  Is there some way I can verify my setup at the server level?

On my server log when I make the request, I see this:

> HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - api/data/documents
>   [/test/testmissupport.nsf/api/data/documents] Anonymous

Comment: This question would be better fit for serverfault.com.

Comment: I guess no..anyway there are quite many server setup related questions here also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be because Anonymous does not have rights. Be sure to login with full access. To verify at server level use:

```
http://hostname/api
```

For Domino 8.5.3 ["server OSGI files must be added to enable the Domino Data Service"](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_admin). These come with Upgrade Pack 1.

Comment: Initially, I had Anonymous as no access, but I also tried it with full access and got the same error.  At the server level like your example, I get 

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unable to Process Request</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <P>Http Status Code: 404</P>
        <P>Reason: File not found or unable to read file</P>
    </BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: DDS should normally return a 403 if access issues. Sounds like DDS is not enabled in the server document, or your URL path is to a non existent NSF.

Comment: For 8.5.3 you need Upgrade Pack 1. Not sure if ExtLib will do the same.

Comment: I've got fix pack 3, wouldn't that cover it?

Comment: No. Upgrade Pack is a different thing.

Comment: Ok, let me check passport advantage and see if I can download that.  Be back in a bit.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to see it on Passport Advantage.  I see up to fix pack 5, but I don't see the upgrade pack 1.  Do you think that's normal?

Comment: Here is some help: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_the_upgrade_pack_from_Passport_Advantage_ddxl853&content=pdcontent

Comment: Just a quick question, would upgrading to 9 also achieve the same thing?  We're in the process of upgrading other servers to 9?

Comment: Yes. That would do it too.

Comment: Thanks.  Might do that instead.  I downloaded upgrade pack 1 and it's a zip file but I can't seem to extract it on Linux or Windows...

Comment: Server is now at 9.0.1 and Domino Data Services is working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with seeing that your server is set up correctly. With the following call.

```
GET http://server:80/api/data
```

If you don't get anything back from that, then your server is not set up correctly.

After that the database you are accessing needs to enabled to use the DDS. To do that.

1. In the Database properties advanced tab, set the database to allow "Views" or "Views and Documents". By default it will not allow DDS access.

   [image: drop down options for DDS App properties]
2. After this you need to also enable which views you allow on the service. You go to the particular view in design, select properties and advanced. There is a check box there.

   [image: checkbox]

Once that is all complete, you should be able to access the View/Document. You would use the following URL sample to get a list of available resources in the database.

```
GET http://server:80/sampleApp.nsf/api/data/collections
```

For more details on this check the following [wiki article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Accessing_IBM_Domino_Access_Services_das901&content=apicontent).